# Retrofit insert query parameters into pre-built string from server

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have a request that returns a query url with an already prebuilt query parameter into it. I need to insert the parameter into the query dynamically. My issue is that retrofit just concatenates the query to the end of the url instead of inserting the data.

Here's an example endpoint that I need to use:

```
mywebsite.com?pagenumber={pageNumber}&pagesize={pageSize}
```

when I use this interface method to setup the url:

```
 @GET
 Call<Model> getdata(@Url String query, @Query("pagenumber") Integer pageNumber, @Query("pagesize") Integer pageSize);
```

it ends up just concatenating to the end of the url

```
mywebsite.com?pagenumber={pageNumber}&pagesize={pageSize}&pagenumber=1&pagesize=10
```

I've tried both cases of "pageNumber" and "pagenumber" fwiw

Answer (score 0):

what the query string is? `mywebsite.com?pagenumber={pageNumber}&pagesize={pageSize}`?

Just use `mywebsite.com`. In this case your params will be added to final request string.

Comment: the params arlready exist in the url. This is a url passed down from a server, so I have no control over the format.

Comment: url in this form comes from server, but values to param are stored on device? Looks a bit strange =\ I'm not sure that it's able in such manner. In this case I see following variation:
programmaticylly replace params values in url string before Call<Model> getdata(@Url String query);
smt like this:
`url = "your value from server"
url = url.replace("{pageNumber}", 100500);
url = url.replace("{pageSize}", 42);
api.getDate(url);`